# c# get youtube playlist using Youtube data api v3

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am currently developing a software for my school. This software must be able to publish videos, but it also must be able to add those video to a playlist.
Question: How can I list all the existing playlist (even empty or private) of the account? I am using YouTube data API v3, and I am unable to get the empty ones.
Here is the code:

```
private async Task Run()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
            );
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
        channelsListRequest.Mine = true;

        // Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the authenticated user's channel.
        var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
        {
            // From the API response, extract the playlist ID that identifies the list
            // of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
            var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

            Console.WriteLine("Videos in list {0}", uploadsListId);

            var nextPageToken = "";
            while (nextPageToken != null)
            {
                var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

                // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
                {
                    // Print information about each video.
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", playlistItem.Snippet.Title, playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                }

                nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this code to work by doing this:

```
private async Task Run()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
            );
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        // var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
        var playlistListRequest = youtubeService.Playlists.List("snippet");
        playlistListRequest.Mine = true;

        // Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the authenticated user's channel.
        var playlistListResponse = await playlistListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        foreach (var playlist in playlistListResponse.Items)
        {
            // From the API response, extract the playlist ID that identifies the list
            // of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
            var playlistListId = playlist.Id;

            Console.WriteLine("Videos in list {0}", playlistListId);
        }
    }
```

Thanks to "not_a_bot" for helping me.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, and it fails. What's the `"snippet"` magic string?

Comment: You need to change the request type.

Comment: example: 'var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails"); channelsListRequest.Mine = true;' become: 'var playlistListRequest = youtubeService.Playlists.List("snippet"); playlistListRequest.Mine = true;' @VioletGiraffe

Comment: Hope this will help you in your project.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused, until I realized I probably need to RTFM. That answered my questions :)